# Compile list of values by searching all the directories in unix

Tags: python, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a directory `/usr/local/` which has some number of sub-directories:

```
/usr/local/service/servicename/er.jca
/usr/local/service/servicename1/er1.jca
...
```

I want to search all *.jca files in those sub-directories and grep the values(filter out) for PackageName and Procedure Name in the format PackageName/Procedure Name for all the jca files, but only under the condition that the *.jca file has

```
className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBStoredProcedureInteractionSpec"
```

The output I am expecting is to list the values of all PackageName/ProcedureName in a txt file. For example, given this .jca file:

```
ex:
 className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBStoredProcedureInteractionSpec">
      <property name="SchemaName" value="APPS"/>
      <property name="PackageName" value="XX"/>
      <property name="ProcedureName" value="process"/>
```

the output should be:

```
XX/process
```

I have tried:

```
 grep -rnw $directory  -e *.jca

$directory=/usr/local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the following file:

```
if grep className=\"oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBStoredProcedureInteractionSpec\" ${1} > /dev/null; then
    x=`grep -e "\(\<property name=\"PackageName\" value=\"\)[^\"]\+" jca.jca | sed "s/.*\<property name=\"PackageName\" value=\"\(.*\)\"\/\>/\1/"`
    y=`grep -e "\(\<property name=\"ProcedureName\" value=\"\)[^\"]\+" jca.jca | sed "s/.*\<property name=\"ProcedureName\" value=\"\(.*\)\"\/\>/\1/"`
    echo ${x}/${y}
fi
```

Call that file `filter.sh`, and then `chmod a+x filter.sh`. `filter.sh` extracts the two items you want into `x` and `y` and then echoes them out to output. There's no doubt a more elegant way of doing this, but it works. Note that you can run `filter.sh` on individual files to verify that its behavior is what you want. After creating `filter.sh`, the following command should do the trick:

```
find ${directory} -name "*.jca" -exec ./filter.sh {} \;
```

This will find all files in directory `${directory}` matching the glob pattern `*.jca`, and then run `filter.sh` on it.

Comment: Hi +Ben Hocking,thanks for the command, but i need to grep only values of Package/Procedures ex:if u check my first post i need the o/p ina text file as: XX/process (package/procedures) for all the *.jca files

Comment: @RajMullapu, I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps if you added a more detailed example, it might help. When you say "grep only values" are you saying you want to have "XX" and "process" returned from your example? Try giving more detail than you think we need.

Comment: yes Ben, as i mentioned in the above example, i want to have XX and process as return values

Comment: @RajMullapu, I have edited your question to reflect what I now suspect you are asking. If I have introduced an error, please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind a Perl solution? This assumes you are running the command in the directory (and subdirs) with all your '*.jca' files.

```
find . -name '*.jca' -exec grep '\(Package\|Procedure\)Name' {} \; | paste - - | perl -ne '/value="(\S+)".+value="(\S+)"/; print "$1/$2\n"'
```

Output given your input file:

```
XX/process
```

Comment: Thanks pcantalupo for the script,but i need shell or python